# How to get Category URL from field in Matrix

Tags: matrix, categories, fieldtypes

This is my Matrix set up:

[image]

I'm stumped to how to get the Categories URL.

```
{% for block in entry.galleriesItem %}
    {% switch block.type %}

        {% case "galleriesItem" %}
            <a href="{{ block.linkTo.first().url() }}">
                <div class="grid-item panel {% if loop.index is divisible by(3) %}last{% endif %}">
                    {% for asset in block.image %}
                        <img src="{{ asset.getUrl }}"  alt="{{ asset.title }}"/>
                    {% endfor %}

                    <div class="bg-white panel__title">
                        <span class="cta-link cta-link--black">{{ block.galleryType }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
    {% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
```

I previously used:

```
{{ block.linkTo.first().url() }}
```

when the field type was an entry.

Comment: Can you copy and paste what it outputs for? <pre>{{ dump( block.linkTo.first() ) }}</pre> Also, what does it output when you do {{ block.linkTo.first().title }}

Comment: Output is massive, is there a certain part I could paste? With {{ block.linkTo.first().title }} I get the error 'Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a null variable'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{{ block.linkTo.first().url() }}` looks basically right, but a couple of things could be going wrong here:

- Does the `Galleries` category have a url assigned? (make sure the "Categories in this group have their own URLs" box is checked)
- Is there a category? You should *always* check, even if it is a required field. You can do `{% if block.linkTo.first() %}...{% endif %}` or `{{ block.linkTo.first().url() ?? '' }}` and use the [A null coalescing operator](https://github.com/TopShelfCraft/QQ).

Comment: That was it, needed the if statement